# Can i get the insights of page facebook where i am not admin ? "with graph api"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can i get the insights of page facebook where i am not admin ? "with graph api"
for exemple:
{page_id}/insights/page_fans?since=2011-01-01&until=2011-05-05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't get all page facebook insights.

Only two insights are public: `page_storytellers_by_country` and `page_fans_country`.

Comment: do you have an idea how socialbakers get all page facebook insights ?

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think they get them all. For instance, on this page (https://www.socialbakers.com/statistics/facebook/pages/total/celebrities/)  they only talk about total fans count and local fans count, which are public insights. 
And if you create a trial analytics, they only show public data. For instance, you can "easily" get all page's posts and determinate by yourself some metrics like which posts got the most engagement. You just have to play with this API call: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed

Comment: yes but he give a benchmake where all the metric is private insights

Comment: are he have api specific from facebook ?

Answer (score 1):

No, of course not. You cannot get Google Analytics insights without being admin of a website either.

You CAN get the CURRENT amount of fans though: `/page-id?fields=fan_count`

...and you can get two public insights:

- `/page-id/insights?metric=page_fans_country`
- `/page-id/insights?metric=age_storytellers_by_country`

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am tolking about page facebook insights

Comment: i know, it was just a side note about the google analytics. would be weird if you could take a look at insights of website (or facebook pages) you don´t own. that´s usually only available for admins.

Comment: ...a simple "no" would be a bit too short for a stackoverflow answer :)